# Json file to HTML table in php

Tags: php, html, json

I'm looking for a way to put JSON content into an html table. I already have a script which prints out my JSON  but I'm having trouble inserting those into an HTML table. Here is my code so far.

```
<?php
  $dir = "/Apache24/htdocs/reservation/JR";
  if (is_dir($dir)) {
    if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {
      foreach(glob("*.json") as $filename) {
        $data = file_get_contents($filename);
        $testing = json_decode($data, true);
        foreach($testing as $testing) {
          echo $testing['Comments']['Manufacturer'] . "<br/>";
          echo $testing['Comments']['Model'] . "<br/>";
          echo $testing['Comments']['BIOSFamily'] . "<br/>";
          echo $testing['Comments']['BIOSDate'] . "<br/>";
          echo $testing['Comments']['SerialNumber'] . "<br/>";
        }
      }
    }
  }
?>
```

Result:

```
  Company
  ProLiant DL380 Gen10
  U30
  05/22/2018
  2M274904KP
```

Comment: Where is your `<table>` element?  Where are you adding `<tr>` and `<td>` elements to it?  Are you just asking how to make an HTML table?  Surely there are examples you can find with even a cursory Google search.

Comment: What, so you just want to know how to `echo "<td>{$testing['Comments']['Manufacturer']}</td>"` ?

Comment: Essentially yes, Ive seen other cases where people parse through the entire JSON file and loop through into a table but im only focused on the first section(the file is about 200 lines itself with over 20 key values) and adding my html tags for table all I receive is errors ie. unexpected <tr> and <td> tags.

Comment: @JohnMonte Solved it here... `:)`

Comment: I need to wait 5 more minutes but I surely will! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What you are doing is totally right, except, you need to create a table and work through it. See the below changes:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Manufacturer</th>
      <th>Model</th>
      <th>BIOSFamily</th>
      <th>BIOSDate</th>
      <th>SerialNumber</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
<?php
  $dir = "/Apache24/htdocs/reservation/JR";
  if (is_dir($dir)) {
    if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {
      foreach(glob("*.json") as $filename) {
        $data = file_get_contents($filename);
        $testing = json_decode($data, true);
        foreach($testing as $testing) {
          echo "<tr>";
          echo "<td>", $testing['Comments']['Manufacturer'], "</td>";
          echo "<td>", $testing['Comments']['Model'], "</td>";
          echo "<td>", $testing['Comments']['BIOSFamily'], "</td>";
          echo "<td>", $testing['Comments']['BIOSDate'], "</td>";
          echo "<td>", $testing['Comments']['SerialNumber'], "</td>";
          echo "</tr>";
        }
      }
    }
  }
?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```